# Change background-color of each word in search bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, search, highlight

I have been trying to spite each word in jQuery and give them a colored background, I found a solution, but it only work for the html content, I want to color the input for search bar. And this an examble for what I found

HTML

```
some content
<div>another content 
    <input id="search" type="text" value="dsfdsfdsf sdf dsfsdfsfs">
</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac turpis
</p>
content in body
```

jQuery

```
//the main point here is you need to replace only the contents of the text node, not all the html parts

var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'gray'];
var lastC;

jQuery('*').contents().each(function () {
    //not a text node or there is no content to replace
    if (this.nodeType != 3 || !this.nodeValue.trim()) {
        return;
    }

    //replace the value of the text node
    $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(/\w+/g, function (part) {
        var c = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
        while (c == lastC) {
            var c = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
        }
        lastC = c;
        return '<span style="background-color: '+c+';">' + part.split("").join("") + '</span>'
    }))
});
```

I tried to change `jQuery('*')` to `jQuery('#search')`  but it didn't work.

Live example 
https://jsfiddle.net/7hs9mgLp/2/

What should I do it fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it cannot works with an text input element because this function get the **content** to englobe it in a **span** element and not the **value** of the element.

But I've made a fix to make it works with your code, with applying a random `color` on the `background` `input` element.

[You can see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/7hs9mgLp/3/)

Here's the JS code :

```
//the main point here is you need to replace only the contents of the text node, not all the html parts

var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'gray'];
var lastC;

jQuery('*').contents().each(function () {
    //not a text node or there is no content to replace
     // here is the part I've changed. I test what is the element we get
     if ( $(this).is( "input" ) ) {
        color = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
        $(this).css('background-color',color);
     }
    else{
      if (this.nodeType != 3 || !this.nodeValue.trim()) {
          return;
      }

      //replace the value of the text node
      $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(/\w+/g, function (part) {
          var c = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
          while (c == lastC) {
              var c = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
          }
          lastC = c;
          return '<span style="background-color: '+c+';">' + part.split("").join("") + '</span>'
      }));
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

To color each words in the input, it's kind of tricky and I don't know if there a "clean" way to do that.

Anyway, here's my suggestion for this part

[See this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hs9mgLp/9/)

I've changed a little the HTML structure to do this because I can't figure out an other way to do it. Hope it helps.

Here's the JS part updated :

```
if ( $(this).is( "input" ) ) {
  val = $(this).val().split(" ");
  $( val ).each(function(i,v ) {
    color = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
    $("label").append("<span class='absolute' style='background-color: "+color+"; '>"+v+"</span>");
    $('#search').css('position','relative');
    $(this).val('');
    $('label').css({'position' : 'absolute', 'left' : '2px', 'top' : '2px' });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me an idea about the solution, but I don't want to whole page to be colored I want each word in the search bar to have a different background color not the whole background as you did. Thank you

Comment: It's kind of tricky to do that but I find a possible way to get the result you wants. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I works as it should now. I don't know how to thank you for you pig help. I really appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I enjoyed this because I never did something like that before :)